# Java Code to save Web page as image

Tags: java

I have an application developed using struts2. One of my web page has a div in which it displays a world map created using Google map API. On click of a button I want to save this map as an image on the server location. I tried this using the ROBOT class but this is not working. My application supports IE8. Below is the code I wrote:

```
Dimension screenDim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(screenDim);
Robot rob = new Robot();
BufferedImage img = rob.createScreenCapture(rect);
String FileName="D:\\SP_Maps\\Map.png";
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(FileName));
```

Basically I tried to take a screen shot of the page on click of a button and save it as an image. This works fine on my local host but, when I deploy this on my server and try to get the screen shot I just get a black page saved as png image.

Comment: *"I tried this using the ROBOT class but this is not working."*  Show us your attempt.  What did you expect to happen?  What happened instead?

Comment: Here is the code I used "Dimension screenDim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(screenDim); Robot rob = new Robot(); BufferedImage img = rob.createScreenCapture(rect); String FileName="D:\\Maps\\Map.png"; ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(FileName));" On click of button i tried to take the screen shot of the desktop and save it as image on the server machine. This works fine on my localhost, but when I deployed the same on my server it's just giving a black page.

Comment: @user2134620 you could edit your question and put that comment well formated in it.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvinience caused. I have now update my post.

Answer (score 0):

While you are developing a web application you may use javascript if you are interested..

To get a screen shot and save it with any format you may use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

```
PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast
and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, 
JSON, Canvas, and SVG.
```

Check those examples written with PhantomJS:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Examples

Also check this tutorial [Taking website screenshots using PhantomJS](http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/taking-website-screenshots-using-phantomjs/)

The tutorial is about taking a web shot and saving it as JPEG, PNG, PDF ... etc

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your use case clearly ? If I understand correctly you have a web application which has a functionality to take a screen capture upon user action? Ideally, Java `Robot` utility should use to do automated testing of java applications. As per the doc

> The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of
>   Java platform implementations.

Maybe you can try using phantomjs. 
example

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    page.render('google.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start

To perform user actions like button clicks, you can use casper.js 
http://casperjs.org/quickstart.html